# Why does the Killing form act on the Cartan subalgebra as $\kappa(h,k)=\sum_\alpha \alpha(h)\alpha(k)$?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Chose a finite dimensional semi-simple Lie algebra $L$ and a Cartan subalgebra $H$. Why do we have $$\kappa_L (h,k)=\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi (L,H)}\alpha(h)\alpha(k),$$ where $\kappa$ is the Killing form and $\Phi(L,H)$ is the set of roots?

I tried to work something out via the root space decomposition and Lie's theorem but I didn't get that far. Any thoughts?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889551/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334606/173147

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $h\in H$. Remember that the action of $\operatorname{ad}(h)$ on $L$ is diagonalisable and that the eigenvalues (other than $0$) are precisely the numbers $\alpha(h)$, with $\alpha\in\Phi(L,H)$. Therefore, with respect to some basis of $L$, the matrix of $\operatorname{ad}(h)$ is a diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are the numbers $\alpha(h)$ ($\alpha\in\Phi(L,H)$) and $0$. If $k$ is another element of $H$, the same thing will be true *with respect to the same basis*. Therefore, the matrix of $\operatorname{ad}(h)\circ\operatorname{ad}(k)$ will be a diagonal matrix whose entries within the main diagonal will be the numbers $\alpha(h)\alpha(k)$ ($\alpha\in\Phi(L,H)$) and $0$. So, its trace is the sum that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you but why are the eigenvalues of $ad(h)$ PRECISELY the numbers $\alpha (h)$? Every $\alpha(h)$ is an eigenvalue but why is every eigenvalue of this form?

Comment: Because, by definition, the roots are those linear forms $\alpha\in H^*$ such that, for each $h\in H$, $\operatorname{ad}(h)$ is diagonalisable and the eigenvalues are the numbers $\alpha(h)$.

Comment: Do you use the root space decomposition at any point in your proof?

Comment: Yes, when I write that, with respect to some basis of $L$, the matrix of $\operatorname{ad}(h)$ is a diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are the numbers $\alpha(h)$ ($\alpha\in\Phi(L,H)$) and $0$.

Comment: Can you explain this in a few words? My problem is: $ad(h):L\to L$ is diagonalisable w.r.t. some basis by definition of Cartan subalgebra. What does this have to do with the decomposition?

Comment: For each $\alpha\in\Phi(L,H)$, pick a basis of $L_\alpha$. Then get the union of all these basis and add to them a basis of $H$. Then you will have a basis of $L$ with the property that I mentioned.

Comment: @user455297 You're welcome. If my answer was useful, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: I have already voted up, but since I have not much reputation it doesn't count...

Answer (score 2):

The Cartan decomposition says that
$$
L=H\oplus \sum_{\alpha\in \Phi}L_{\alpha}.
$$
The matrices of the restrictions of $ad(h)$ to $L_{\alpha}$ for $h\in H$ can be taken simultaneously in lower-triangular form with diagonal $(\alpha(h),\ldots ,\alpha(h))$ by Lie's Theorem. With $\dim L_{\alpha}=1$ and taking the trace we obtain that
$$
\kappa(h,k)=tr(ad(h)\cdot ad(k))=\sum_{\alpha\in \Phi}\alpha(h)\alpha(k)
$$
for $h,k\in H$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but why can we apply Lie's theorem since $L$ is not solvable and why has the diagonal the form you mentioned?

Comment: Because of the Cartan subalgebra, which is solvable. Note that we only consider $ad(h)$ for $h\in H$.